# how do you use emcc to compile javascript code to a wasm file?

Tags: javascript, webassembly, emscripten

The example I was given is:

emcc sample.js -o test.wasm -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['main']"

where `sample.js` is:

```
function main() {
        console.log('hi');
}
```

but I get `wasm-ld: error: unknown file type: sample.js`

Comment: emcc is C/C++ Compiler, and it can not compile javascript. It seems like XY problem.